Definition of $\eta_t$ is ambiguous (?)
I'm reading the paper Limit Theorems for Multitype Continuous Time Markov Branching Processes, I. The Case of an Eigenvector Linear Functional (1969) by Athreya, and in the proof of Lemma 3 it says, that as $t\to\infty$, $\eta_t\to0$, and this step is crucial for the proof.
But this is defined as $$\eta_t=\inf_{t_\eta\le t}\eta,$$ which is absolutely non-sense and ambiguous to me. I would maybe understand if $\eta$ would, in some way, be a fucntion or a variable dependent on $t$, but up until now $\eta$ was always just a positive constant.
Just before this, in the paper it is written:

Fix an $\varepsilon>0$. Then for $\forall\eta>0,\exists t_\eta\ni$ $$t\ge t_\eta\implies Pr\{|d(Y_1(t)e^{-\lambda_1t,I})-d(W,I)|>\eta\}\le\varepsilon$$ where $d(x,I)=\inf_{y\in I}|x-y|$. For $\forall t>0$, set $\eta_t=\inf_{t_\eta\le t}\eta$,$$B_t=\{\omega:d(Y_1(t)e^{-\lambda_1t},I)\le \eta_t\}$$

I just rewrote exactly what is written, no need to explain functions and properties, but maybe, since this is a "relatively old" paper, it may have also "old" notation, which someone could get me to understand.

We first define, for all $\eta > 0$, a value $t_\eta$ satisfying some long condition I will assume you understand, because you are not asking questions about it.
From here, $\inf\limits_{t_\eta \le t} \eta$ should be read as $\inf \{ \eta : t_\eta \le t\}$. That is, if we define $E_t = \{\eta : t_\eta \le t\}$ (the set of all $\eta$ such that $t_\eta \le t$), then we define $\eta_t = \inf E_t$, the greatest lower bound on $E_t$.
Notably, the variable names $t$ and $\eta$ are "doubled up" here, with both of them referring to a function and an input to that function. We could also, equally well, define $$\eta_s = \inf_{t_x \le s} x$$ and get the same definition of $\eta_t$ for all $t$ (of $\eta_s$ for all $s$, which is the same).
